# how to assign the address of a variable to NULL in C?

Tags: c, pointers

I have a question in C, how to assign the address of a variable to NULL?

For example:

```
int a;
```

And how to assign the address of variable a to NULL?

Comment: `NULL` is a value, not an object. You cannot assign to values. You cannot assign *anything* to `42`.

Answer (score 4):

You got it backwards, you can't change the address of a variable. The compiler places it wherever it feels like, and the address becomes what it becomes.

What you can do is use a pointer:

```
int *a = NULL;
```

This of course means that the address of `a`, the pointer variable whose value is `NULL`, is *not* `NULL`, just as with `int a;`.

In some implementations (like for embedded systems where there is no operating system) you *can* control where (`static` only, typically) variables reside exactly, by instructing the linker and sometimes also by explicitly adding compiler-specific invocations that put various declarations into different segments. The segments are then laid out by the linker into the available memory.

Answer (score 3):

You can't change the address of a variable, nor need to.